# How do I add two or three cells together and then multiply by 2 in excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have two (sometimes 3 or 4) cells that I want to add together in a new cell and if the first two (or 3 or 4) cells are populated I want to multiply the answer by two

Is this possible?
And how do you do it if it is.

*edit* sorry if that didn't make much sense

I'm working in google sheets

Hopefully this will make sense

Column C has two entries for example in C7 and C8.
For C9, if C7 and C8 are populated then I want it to add C7 and C8 together - but only if it's populated with a number above 0.

Comment: Question unclear. Need examples. Also is this for excel or google sheets?

Comment: It would also be useful to see what you tried

Comment: =sum(A1:A3)*and(Isnumber(A1),isnumber(A2,isnumber(A3)*2

Comment: Fab! @SolarMike that's what I need it to do. Thank you!

Comment: Fab! @SolarMike that's what I need it to do. Thank you!... .. this is the two together that works... =sum(C7:C8)*and(Isnumber(C7),isnumber(C8)*2) and this is the three together.. =sum(C11:C13)*and(Isnumber(C11),isnumber(C12),isnumber(C13)*2) .. THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=SUM(A1:A4)*2
```

if cells are not next to each other you can do:

```
=SUM(A1; D5; G12)*2
```